# how does Cpython implement its type Objects, i.e. type's type is always type?

Tags: python, types, implementation, cpython, pyobject

I understand that everything in python is an Object and that the 'type' (or class) of these object is 'type'. Plus the type of type is also type itself. (as explained nicely [here](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html))

What I do not understand is how is this circular reference implemented? So i looked [here](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html). To quote the portion which might explain what I am looking for:

```
PyTypeObject* PyObject.ob_type
```

**This is the type’s type, in other words its metatype. It is initialized by the argument to the PyObject_HEAD_INIT macro, and its value should normally be &PyType_Type. However, for dynamically loadable extension modules that must be usable on Windows (at least), the compiler complains that this is not a valid initializer. Therefore, the convention is to pass NULL to the PyObject_HEAD_INIT macro and to initialize this field explicitly at the start of the module’s initialization function, before doing anything else. This is typically done like this:**

```
Foo_Type.ob_type = &PyType_Type;
```

Since C is not OOP based, I understand that when one creates a class, it can have an attribute to point to the object itself as its own class. I am sure that my lack of understanding here has led me in a state of confusion, can anyone point out if this is a usual practice in design of other scripting languages or some kind of a pattern, if anyone can throw some light on this, I will be grateful for it.

**EDIT :** I found out [here](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/type.html#PyType_Type) that:

```
PyObject* PyType_Type
```

**This is the type object for type objects; it is the same object as type and types.TypeType in the Python layer.**

How is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that defines PyType_Type.ob_type = &PyType_Type involves a couple of indirections. It all starts in the function `_Py_ReadyTypes()` when it calls `PyType_Ready(&PyType_Type)`. Before the function is called, the members `tp_base` and `ob_type` are both `NULL`. The function first sets `type->tp_base` to `&PyBaseObject_Type` (which is `object` in Python space) and then sets `type->ob_type = PyBaseObject_Type.ob_type`. The code uses `Py_TYPE()` which is just a macro for `ob->ob_type`. Since the type of object is type the code sets the type of type to type.

Now you have:

```
>>> type.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
>>> type(object)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(type(object))
<class 'type'>
```

The definition makes type an instance of object plus itself and object an instance of type.

```
>>> isinstance(type, object)
True
>>> isinstance(object, type)
True
>>> isinstance(type, type)
True
```

The type initialization code is much easier to understand in Python pseudo-code:

```
# object's class is type
object.__class__ = type
# PyType_Ready(type) sets:
type.__bases__ = (object,)
type.__class__ = type(object)
```

Comment: Thanks Tiran for your nice answer but What confuses me is that how can an object have NULL as its class type? Does it then mean, that they are not the regular classes (as in OOP) but are classes being defined in C for python?

Comment: It's a boot strapping thing. The relationship between object and type is cyclic. Somehow the code must define the cyclic structure so it starts with NULL and sets the proper values a bit later.The types are initialized very early in the start phase of the interpreter. User code can never see NULL as base class or type.

Comment: Thanks Tiran for your quick answers, this would then be a usual process for creating the classes etc. in other languages too! I am actually looking for a understanding of how the oop structure is even designed in the first place and for that matter, even in C++?, maybe that would give a very good insight on how such cyclic initializations can be done....